# Browser history needs a DOM error when rendering react-router v4 and redux on the server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux, react-router, react-router-v4

I'm trying to server-render content for my app that uses react-router v4,redux, and express but I get `Browser history needs a DOM` error in the terminal. I also use react-router-config to keep my routes more organized. Saw a solution that suggested that one should create the store on the server, so I tried copypasting the code from store.js file to the server, however it didn't work out. What can I do to fix this extremely unpleasant error?

routes.js

```
const routes = (
        {
            component: App,
            routes: [
                {
                    path: '/',
                    exact:true,
                    component: Home
                },
                {
                    path: '/login',
                    exact:true,
                    component: Login
                },
                {
                    path: '/registration',
                    exact:true,
                    component: Registration
                },
                {
                    path: '/person/:id',
                    exact:true,
                    component: UserPage
                },
                {
                    path: '/myPage',
                    exact:true,
                    component: MyPage
                },
                {
                    path: '/goodBye',
                    exact:true,
                    component: GoodBye
                },
                {
                    path: '*',
                    component: NoMatch
                }
            ]
        }
    );
```

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
//import '../styles/app.scss'
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import {Grid} from 'react-bootstrap';
import store from './store/store';
import routes from './routes';
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
import { syncHistoryWithStore } from 'react-router-redux';
import { renderRoutes } from 'react-router-config';
import { BrowserRouter as Router} from 'react-router-dom';
import { ConnectedRouter, Switch } from 'connected-react-router';

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Provider store={store}>
                <Grid fluid={true}>
                    <ConnectedRouter history={createBrowserHistory()}>
                        <Switch>
                            {renderRoutes(routes)}
                        </Switch>
                    </ConnectedRouter>
                </Grid>
            </Provider>
        );   
    }
} 

const isBrowser = typeof window !== 'undefined';

if(isBrowser) {
  ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
}
```

Route handler:

```
import express from 'express';
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server';
import routes from '../../js/routes';
import {StaticRouter} from 'react-router';
import { renderRoutes } from 'react-router-config';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from '../../js/store/store';
const router = express.Router();

router.get('*',(req,res) => {
    let context = {};
    const content = renderToString(
        <Provider store={store}>
            <StaticRouter location={req.url} context={context}>
                {renderRoutes(routes)}
            </StaticRouter>
        </Provider>
    );
    if(context.status === 404) {
        res.status(404);
    }
    res.render('index', {title: 'Express', data: store.getState(), content });
});
```